# IUPAC naming for a ring system containing different ring structures

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, hydrocarbons

Regarding the IUPAC naming convention for compounds in which one ring is more highly $\pi$-conjugated than the other ring but contains fewer carbon atoms:

[image]

I can name this compound as either:

(a) **1-[cyclohexenyl]-cyclopenta-1,3-diene**, giving preference to the ring with the greater number of $\pi$ bonds; or

(b) **1-[cyclopenta-1,3-dienyl]-cyclohexenyl**, giving preference to the ring with the greater number of carbon atoms.

What is the correct answer?

Comment: Before deciding the parent structure, there are two problems. Firstly, why square brackets? You only need square brackets as a second layer if you already have parentheses. If not, you should only use parentheses. Secondly, hyphens are not used to separate substituents from the main part of the name. You don’t say 2-methyl-butane, right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use "cyclopenta-1,3-diene" in the end of the name (your first attempt), then this would be the stem system.  In case like the one presented in the question -- two rings connected *via* a single bond -- it is recommended to recognize the cyclohexene as the stem (like parent), and the cyclopentadienyl moiety as a substituent (like child).  Because counting the number of ring atoms has a higher priority, than the number of double / triple bonds in the cycles, your second attempt is *in this perspective* the *better* one of the two.

To detail out the substituent, use *normal* parentheses. Square brackets would be suitable e.g., to describe annulated bicyclohexanes' bridges (e.g., [decalin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decalin) as bicyclo[4.4.0]decane); however, this motif is not present in your structure.

This yields the name of: 1-(cyclopenta-1,3-dien-1-yl)cyclohex-1-ene

**Addition**: The answer by Safdar Faisal refers to the 2013 edition of IUPAC's [*Blue Book*](https://iupac.org/what-we-do/books/bluebook/) (online content [here](https://www.qmul.ac.uk/sbcs/iupac/BlueBook/)).  IUPAC published  a *brief guide* about this revision (Hellwich *et al.* 2020) with the following flow chart relevant to the original question:

[image]

and specific polychromatic examples e.g., about structures with two cycles joined by a single bond:

[image]

As SI to this publication, there equally is [a four-page excerpt](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/pac-2019-0104/downloadAsset/suppl/j_pac-2019-0104_suppl.pdf) available, too.

**Reference**:  Hellwich K.-H.; Hartshorn R. M.; Yerin A.; Damhus T.;  Hutton A. T. Brief guide to the nomenclature of organic chemistry (IUPAC Technical Report). *Pure Appl. Chem.* **2020**, *92*, 527-539; [doi 10.1515/pac-2019-0104](https://doi.org/10.1515/pac-2019-0104) (open access).

Answer (score 10):

You have two choices for choosing the parent hydride here in this case.

#### 1. Choosing the cyclohexene ring as the parent hydride

If we consider the cyclohexene ring as the parent hydride, we get the cyclopentadiene ring to be a substituent leading the name to become **1-(cyclopenta-1,3-dien-1-yl)cyclohex-1-ene**

#### 2. Choosing the cyclopentadiene as the parent hydride

If we choose the cyclopentadiene as the parent hydride, the cyclohexene ring becomes the substituent and  we get the name of the compound to be **1-(cyclohex-1-en-1-yl)cyclopenta-1,3-diene**

Now, what do we choose - the cyclopentadiene or the cyclohexene?

#### The preferred IUPAC naming

According to **P-44.2.1** of the *Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)*, we gain the rules to determine seniority in ring systems.

> **P-44.2.1** The senior ring or ring system:
>
> (a) is a heterocycle;
>
> (b) has at least one nitrogen atom;
>
> (c) has at least one heteroatom (in the absence of nitrogen) that occurs earlier in the following sequence:
>
> F > Cl > Br > I > O > S > Se > Te > P > As > Sb > Bi > Si > Ge > Sn > Pb > B > Al > Ga > In > Tl;
>
> (d) has the greater number of rings;
>
> (e) has the greater number of skeletal atoms;
>
> (f) has the greater number of heteroatoms of any kind;
>
> (g) has the greater number of heteroatoms occurring earlier in the sequence:
>
> F > Cl > Br > I > O > S > Se > Te > N > P > As > Sb > Bi > Si > Ge > Sn > Pb > B > Al > Ga > In > Tl.

Therefore, via **P-44.2.1** (e), we have the cyclohexene ring as the the main parent hydride. Therefore, the name found in choice 1 is the PIN of the compound. Thus, the PIN of the compound becomes **1-(cyclopenta-1,3-dien-1-yl)cyclohex-1-ene**

[image: 1-(cyclopenta-1,3-dien-1-yl)cyclohex-1-ene]

Comment: Because our university library did not (yet) engage in purchasing the 2013 edition of the Blue Book (neither paper, nor electronic).  So it was a nice find (eventually) that there is a brief guide addressing at least *some* points (cf. vide infra).  Do you know if the current Blue Book equally contains such flow charts and examples where color is used to highlight the structure motifs?

Comment: @Buttonwood IIRC the blue book is black and white only and it isn't actually text searchable with the pdf. So you have to do an OCR of your own if you would like to use that...

Comment: @Martin-マーチン I thought a text of reference *this* relevant would retain the text layer.  So the content mirror from Queen Mary University and *Brief Guide* mentioned below may be more accessible from the get-go.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン As it happens, an [HTML version](https://www.qmul.ac.uk/sbcs/iupac/BlueBook/) of the Blue Book was just published last month. Sadly, search engines have not gotten around to indexing it yet.

Comment: @Buttonwood I've found that OCR works reasonably well on the Blue Book PDF; the main annoyance is that names can pick up extraneous spaces around their punctuation, and `1` is often mistaken for `l`. The online HTML version is probably the better option now that it exists, though.

Comment: Finally! Thanks, @LegionMammal978. Even though this is not for actual learning, it should probably included in the 'Resources' Q&A.